# Way to redirect to a page when user's session is active using Auth in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-blade

I'm working on a project with Laravel 5.7 and I'm trying to redirect to a route when there is an active session. Currently I have tried with this code placed at the top of my view but it just doesn't seems to work.

```
@php
    if(!empty(Auth::user())) {
        header('Location: '.route('dashboard'));
    }
@endphp
```

Is there an error on my code? or Is there another way to do what I'm trying? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you do it in controller?

Comment: @Ash-b Thank you I placed the code in the controller and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do redirect in view file you can use auth middleware in your route file as below

```
<?php

   //route which don't required login session

    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
       //list of routes which you need to access after login
    });
?>
```

routes which you don't required login session that you can write outside of above scope

Answer (score 0):

Why would you check something like that in a view , you should check it in your controller before returning a view.

anyway here is what u can use in your blade template

```
@if(Auth::user())
  <script>window.location = "/dashboard";</script>
@else 
  <script>window.location = "/login";</script>
@endif
```

and remember if auth::user is empty that means user is not registered BUT you can check it with Auth::guest() too , meaning the user has not been registered.

Hope it helps.